# Resizing subview with superview's frame change

Tags: ios, animation

I have a UIImageView aSuper; This view is changing its sizes when i flip it i.e. it is taking sizes of next frame and next frame and so on.

Now this UIImageView contains a subview which is also imageview. I will call it bSubView.

Now i want to resize this bSubView every time its parent's view frame changes.

Code is :- Here invisibleView is subview and viewHolder is parent view. parent view is changing right but problem is with subview.

```
 UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString1]]];

            UIImageView *viewHolder=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(510, 200, 20, 20)];

              invisibleView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
              invisibleView.image=image;               
              invisibleView.frame=viewHolder.bounds;

            viewHolder.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
            [ invisibleView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
            invisibleView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;                
            viewHolder.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"EmptyPlanet"];                  
            [viewHolder addSubview:invisibleView];  

            [self.view addSubview:viewHolder];
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: after the flip action just add this line.
    invisibleView.frame=viewHolder.bounds;

Comment: Yah but it is cropping image that UIImageView(subview) holds?

Comment: add property scalesToFit to it. That will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the inherited method `-(void)layoutsubviews`

This method is called on the super view when its frame changes. In that method you can configure your subviews

Another option is to use autolayout when configuring the subviews.